# \graphicpath and FAT system

Tags: windows, filesystem-access

Well, for some reason that I will try to find out later, my TeX Live under Linux doesn't work anymore and I had to go through windows emulated system.

The file I work with include a `\graphicspath` command, but it seems that the "\" specific to windows path makes problem. The only I had to solve the error messages was to put all files in the same directory without spaces in the path.

Does anyone had experienced such kind of problems and solved it?

Thanks for help

Comment: Use normal slashes.

Comment: Indeed, spaces in file and directory names are evil.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since the backslash has a special meaning in TeX, all distributions for Windows allow substituting it with `/` in file paths. For allowing spaces in file and directory names, load also the `grffile` package.

Comment: Thanks for your answers (and explanations egreg). It works and this problem is solved.